# How to select Unknown Number of Columns in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause, information-schema

Given the table and names of some columns, I have the following Information schema select query.

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
                FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
                    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'm_college'
                    AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'm_fee'
                    AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('id', 'classid', 'semid')
```

But this select does not give me the rows value for each unknown column I select. All I got is names of the unknown columns. Is it possible to select the values of the rows so that I can have column as key and rows as value pair in my php script? I need to insert the column names and row values in other table. Please help or suggest.

Comment: why don't you use select *

Comment: Because I want dynamic columns.

Comment: The INFORMATION_SCHEME only hold meta data, i.e. data about data. It is used by MYSQL to record and know what schemas/databases/tables/fields/field-types/indexes etc etc exists within this MYSQL Server instance. It does not hold the actual data you store in your database.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Thanks for the info. So can you suggest any alternative way to extract the unknown columns

Comment: Why do you have to use specific column names, that is what is confusing all of us?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have a table with dynamic column creation, I need to get all the columns and their row values insert into one column in other table. Please suggest.

Comment: any chance your table is highly de-normalized, like creating columns on the fly ? For daily data

Comment: I think @Drew has a good point. This sounds like extremly bad database design I suppose it is to late to redesign your database?

Comment: This is an intranet project. Please suggest better design which support dynamic column creation.

Comment: how about if we suggest a better design for a database. post your schema. We don't like [XY Problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Wait..I will post it

Comment: Have a look at this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ada44

Comment: so what is the dynamic part, adding new fee types at the end on the fly? If so, an intersect table is the most flexible and rational, versus querying for the structure then using prepared statements

Comment: This is going to sound silly, but do you mean the table gets ROWS added dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a very quick attempt at showing an intersect table.

This allows you to have a fixed structure and add fee types on the fly.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mz_fee222` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `classid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `semid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `batch` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `session` int(11) NOT NULL
);

create table fee_type
(   fee_id int auto_increment primary key,
    description varchar(100)
);
insert fee_type (description) values ('exam'),('marksheet'),('admitcard'),('centre'),('practical'); -- etc as you go

create table mz_fee_intersect
(   -- here is where the fee amount is stored. Flexible.
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    mz_id int not null, -- this is the id from my_fee222 table
    fee_id int not null, -- this is the fee_id from fee_type table
    fee int not null, -- here is the actual fee, like 100 bucks
    -- FK's below (not shown):

    -- 
    unique key (mz_id,fee_id) -- forbids duplicates
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM table_name` selects all of the columns and their values from `table_name`. What you are using selects all of the column names from the schema table (which does not contain the information in your `table_name`).

You can use `SELECT * FROM table_name` in PHP and just use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to get an associative array which is basically a `key => value` array where the `key` is the column name and the `value` is the value for that column in the given row in the array.

Pulled Directory from the PHP docs (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) because you wanted an example:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: I need because I want to dynamically insert column name as row value in other table.

Comment: You can use the above in PHP and just use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to get an associative array which is basically a `key => value` array where the `key` is the column name and the `value` is the value for that column in the given row in the array.

Comment: There are numerous tutorials out there on the internet, can I suggest you look at a few of them. Then there is always [the manual, written in many languages](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/index.php) A radical idea I realise, but when all else fails!!!!

Comment: SELECT * FROM WHERE COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('id', 'semid')..this is what I need. I have to skip certain column with its row value. I have already tried your answer, and it does not work because we have to specify the column name. The column name is unknown. So $row['unknown']

Comment: Just so you know, `array_keys($row)` will give you all of the column names in the row.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I cannot think why you have a table that gets columns added dynamically other than the obvious but here is a suggestion that I hope helps

If you run a `DESCRIBE tablename` and collect the results you get a result set something like this.

```
Field       Type                Null    Key    Default  Extra

id          int(10) unsigned    NO      PRI    NULL     auto_increment
parent_id   int(11)             NO      MUL    0    
lft         int(11)             NO      MUL    0    
rgt         int(11)             NO             0    
level       int(10) unsigned    NO             NULL 
name        varchar(50)         NO      UNI    NULL 
title       varchar(100)        NO             NULL 
rules       varchar(5120)       NO             NULL
```

If you load this into an array, and then drop the Rows you dont want to select in the later query, you get their column names (in Field column) and even their data types if you want them.

You can then use this array, to build the field list for your column specific query and you also know what to call them when you are processing any results.

I hope this helps.