# Add column with FK to an existing table in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, if-statement, alter

Good day everyone. Hope someone can helps me in my experiments.

I have a simple Table for my needs and it's even have some data inside.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT exists main.test (
ID INT(11) NOT NULL, 
NAME varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
DATE_CREATED timestamp NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

But then I should update this table with adding column FK_.

How can I check if table had already has field FK_? 
If such column is not exist do:

```
ALTER TABLE main.test
ADD COLUMN FK INT(11),
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FK)
REFERENCES test2(ID_test2)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL check if a table exists without throwing an exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525784/mysql-check-if-a-table-exists-without-throwing-an-exception)

Comment: do you want to create a foreign key constraint or add a column? Are you sure you want to add a column?

Comment: please check out this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32097401/1816093) I just wrote up for a guy that thought adding columns on the fly was what he really wanted to do. In his case, it was not. May not be your issue. Good luck ! And Welcome to the Stack

Comment: @Drew Greate thanks!
Yep, I need to add new column and set it as FK. 
And then, possible, I'll be need to add one more column with fk and update data to new structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I use java decision of my problem was using ResultSet.

```
ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery(query);
set.next();
int result = set.getInt(1); //it always return only one row
set.close();
```

And this is my sql-query:

```
SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
TABLE_SCHEMA = 'main'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'test'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'FK";
```

When I'll get a result I can decide what query I should to use.